# Every irreducible component of a hypersurface in $ \mathbb{A}^{n}_{\mathbb{C}} $ or $ \mathbb{P}^{n}_{\mathbb{C}} $ has codimension 1?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I accept this statement as true. That's not my difficulty.

Shafarevich claims in Volume 1 of "Basic Algebraic Geometry" that it is enough to consider the case of a hypersurface in $ \mathbb{A}^{n}_{\mathbb{C}}. $ Why is this the case?

Does it have something to do with the fact that $ \mathbb{P}^{n}_{\mathbb{C}} = \bigsqcup_{i=0}^{n} \mathbb{A}^{i}_{\mathbb{C}}$ ?

Comment: An irreducible component $C\subset X\subset \Bbb{P}^n$ always has a dense subset  $C \cap \Bbb{A}^n$ for some copy of $\Bbb{A}^n$ such that $(\Bbb{P}^n-\Bbb{A}^n)\cap C$ is of dimension $< \dim(C)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$ and let $C$ be one of its irreducible components.  Then $C$ intersects one of the $n+1$ copies of $\mathbb{A}^n$ that cover $\mathbb{P}^n$; call that copy $U$.  Then $U\cap C$ is a dense open subvariety of $C$ and so has the same dimension, and $U\cap C$ is an irreducible component of the hypersurface $U\cap X$ in $U\cong \mathbb{A}^n$.  So, if we know the result for $\mathbb{A}^n$, we conclude that $U\cap C$ has dimension $n-1$ and thus so does $C$.